# Output to Input in C

Tags: c, input, save, output

```
if( check_ls(vektor[0]) == 1 ) {
    else{
    dirHandle = opendir(".");
    if (dirHandle) {
    while (0 != (dirEntry = readdir(dirHandle))) {
            if(strcmp(dirEntry->d_name, ".") == 0 ||
           strcmp(dirEntry->d_name, "..") == 0){
            continue;
            }
    puts(dirEntry->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dirHandle);
    }
    }
```

How can i save the output to use it again in an other function?

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions:

1. Read the output in another program (using a pipe)
2. freopen() stdout and write to a file, reading from that file.
3. Best solution: write to a string instead of stdout (use snprintf() instead of puts())